# Start multiple rsync sessions

Tags: bash, rsync, gnu-screen

I want to start multiple rsync sesssions via screen in detached mode?
Is it possible?
I need to run rsync script for each file in folder.

```
screen -t -d sshpass -p 123456 rsync5 rsync -avzP /home/vagrant/test_folder/ user@1.1.1.1:/home/user/test_folder/
```

But it returns **Must be connected to a terminal**.

Comment: `tmux` is easier to automate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So if you need to start multiple rsync sessions try next solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
# paths for rsync in "/folder/folder/folder" format
export SRCDIR="$1"
export DESTDIR="$2"
# Number of threads for xargs
export THREADS="20"
cd $SRCDIR; find . ! -type d -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -P$THREADS -I% rsync  -az % 1.1.1.1:/$DESTDIR/%
```

If you use key auth you may use ssh-agent for automate entering a passphrase for your key.

```
ssh-agent bash
ssh-add /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa
Enter passphrase for /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa: 
Identity added: /home/username/.ssh/id_rsa (/home/username/.ssh/id_rsa)
```

Links:

1. https://wiki.ncsa.illinois.edu/display/~wglick/Parallel+Rsync
2. https://askubuntu.com/questions/362280/enter-ssh-passphrase-once